# Python regular expression search text file count substring

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search

I am attempting to use a regular expression statement in python to search a text file and count the number of times a user defined word appears. When I run my code though, instead of getting a sum of the number of times that unique word appears in the file, I am getting a count for the number lines within that file contain that word.

Example: the word 'apple' exists 56 times in the text file. Appearing in 20 of the total 63 lines of text. When I run my code the console prints '20' for the count of 'apple' instead of the correct '56'.

I thought by using the re.findall() method it would fix this, but it has not.

```
import re

#If user selects Regular Expressions as their search method
elif user_search_method == "2":
    print "\n>>> You selected the Regular Expressions search method"
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    words = sum(1 for w in f if re.findall(user_search_value, w, re.M|re.I))
    f.close()
    print("Your search value of '%s' appears %s times in this file" % (user_search_value, words))
```

Comment: That's exactly what you're asking for, though. `1 for w in f` < here `w` is a line, which you're filtering based on `if re.findall(...)`. If you want to count the number of matches found, sum over `len(re.findall(...))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just adding 1 if it matches, I guess you don't want the search to go over lines, so you can do this:

```
words = sum(len(re.findall(user_search_value, w, re.M|re.I)) for w in f)
```

Comment: Worked!  Thank you.